# Upgrade from 14.04.4 to 16.04

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, updates, 16.04

New release was released at 21 April, but I can't update yet.
I have ***Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS*** but

```
do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
No new release found
```

If I add -d flag it found new release but I can't understand why need this option because I want update from LTS to LTS. It's because 14.04.**4**? Or this update is not yet available?

Every other questions told to add **-d** option, but from LTS to LTS should update without this options. I'm right?